# Specialized filtering by FK in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am building an app to track production in a facility. I have an model representing inputs and a model representing a process, with the process model having a FK to the input model.

```
def Inputs(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField()
    in_stock = models.BooleanField()

def Process(models.Model):
    date =  models.DateField()
    input_item = models.ForeignKey("Inputs")
```

I want to be able to filter the list of inputs that show up in the admin form of the process model. That I already figured out how to do. (Found in Django Docs);

```
class ProcessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "input_items":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Inputs.objects.filter(in_stock=True)
        return super(ProcessAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The problem is as follows; I want to filter the available models based on what inputs are currently in stock, but I also want to be able to access older records which record items which are no longer in stock. The current setup will not show those items when I try to access that old record.

Comment: Older objects refers to what? Now you are getting the stock which are in stock right? You want to get items that are not in stock? Or something else?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. You are filtering Inputs, not processes. Where do you want to access older records?

Comment: When I enter a record of 'process' I want that available options are all 'in_stock'. As time goes on items that were in stock are no longer in stock. So let's say I want to access a record that was inputted one month ago, those inputs are no longer in stock, but I still want to see those records as I entered them last month. The way it is set up now - when I try to access the record from a month ago - the record appears blank in the admin change form, as the item that was entered then is no longer in stock, and is being filtered out.

Comment: When you access old records, the items that are no longer in stock are not shown in the form, right?
What does differentiate the records that display the other items and those that do not? Creation/Update?

Comment: @cdvv7788 you formulated my issue very well. When I create I record I want this filtering in place, but when I read/update I want no filtering to occur.

Comment: The faster way that comes to mind is to modify the form instead of the model admin. Something like this should work (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/s9a0J6fKgWs). I don't know if there is a more clean approach to do that in the modeladmin directly.